# Javascript entries() not returning anything

Tags: javascript, enumerate

I want to get the array elements, with their indexes, I use entries() as below but it does not print out anything, and it does not give any errors.

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var iterator1 = array1.entries();

for ([k, v] in iterator1) {
  console.log(k, v)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `for of` instead of `for in`

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var iterator1 = array1.entries();

for ([k, v] of iterator1) {
  console.log(k, v)
}
```

---

Another way is to use `done` property and `next` method of `iterators`

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var iterator1 = array1.entries();
let result = iterator1.next()

while (!result.done) {
  let [k, v] = result.value
  console.log(k, v)
  result = iterator1.next()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use index and element of an array, you can use the `const [key, value]` notation in conjunction with the `of` keyword, in order to use the iterator.

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (const [index, element] of a.entries()) {
  console.log(index, element);
}

// 0 'a' 
// 1 'b' 
// 2 'c'
```

You could also call next on the iterator directly.

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var iterator1 = array1.entries();

console.log(iterator1.next().value);
// expected output: Array [0, "a"]

console.log(iterator1.next().value);
// expected output: Array [1, "b"]
```

See also: [Mozilla docs - Array.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)